# asp.net custom basepage has a public property for a repeater,prevent designer from adding protected variable for that repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom base page class:

```
//MobileFunnelPage.cs  
public abstract class MobileFunnelPage : Page  
{  
    public virtual Repeater myRepeater{get;set;}  
}
```

Then I have a page that inherits that page:

```
//ConcreteMobileFunnelPage.aspx.cs  
public class ConcreteMobileFunnelPage: MobileFunnelPage  
{  
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){  
        myRepeater.DataSource = new string[]{"Error 1","Error 2","Error 3"};  
        myRepeater.DataBind();  
    }  
}
```

With the following markup:

```
//ConcreteMobileFunnelPage.aspx
<%@ Page Title="ConcreteMobilePage!" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ConcreteMobileFunnelPage.aspx.cs" inherits="MyNamespace.ConcreteMobileFunnelPage" %>  
...  
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" Visible="false">  
<HeaderTemplate>  
    <div>  
        <span>  
</HeaderTemplate>  
<ItemTemplate><li><%# Container.DataItem %></li></ItemTemplate>  
<FooterTemplate>  
</span>  
    </div>  
</FooterTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>
```

The asp.net designer is constantly regenerating and adding protected variables for myRepeater in the designer.cs file:

```
//ConcreteMobilFunnelPage.aspx.designer.cs
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater myRepeater;
```

This causes a problem because it is not overriding the inherited myRepeater property, it is hiding it.  Is there a way to get the designer to honor that myRepeater inherited property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit more wordy, but I think the simplest workaround is to make the property abstract and implement it with the generated field as the backing field:

```
//MobileFunnelPage.cs  
public abstract class MobileFunnelPage : Page  
{  
    public abstract Repeater MyRepeater { get; set; }  
}

//ConcreteMobileFunnelPage.aspx.cs  
public class ConcreteMobileFunnelPage : MobileFunnelPage  
{  
    public override Repeater MyRepeater {
        get {
           return myRepeater;
        }
        set {
           myRepeater = value;
        }
    }
}
```

(Here myRepeater is the protected auto-generated field, and I've renamed the public property to MyRepeater)

As an aside, you should probably remove the setter, I don't think it serves any purpose here.

Comment: that's exactly what i ended up doing... (removing the setter and all.)